# Combine IS NULL and :value in Doctrine 2 DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Since other (old) questions didn't get proper answers, I'll try it again:

I regularly come across a scenario, where I want to query an entity with a specific value:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent = :parent');
$query->setParameter('parent', $parent);
```

Often, this value can be NULL, but `WHERE e.parent = NULL` yields no results, forcing me to hack around like this:

```
if ($parent === null) {
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent IS NULL');
}
else {
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent = :parent');
    $query->setParameter('parent', $parent);      
}
```

While I understand the rationale behind NULL != NULL in SQL / DQL, the fact is, the consequence is really annoying in this case.

Also, an example given in an older question doesn't work in DQL, for NULL != NULL.

```
->setParameter('parent', (is_null($parent) ? "NULL" : $parent));
```

I also tried this way, what someone kindly offered, but this will give a NonUniqueResult exception, because when parent is 1 for example, it'll give a double result.

```
SELECT e 
FROM Entity e 
WHERE (e.parent = :parent OR e.parent IS NULL)
```

**Is there a cleaner way to perform this query, when the parameter can be null?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure regarding your parameter value then you can rewrite your where clause as

```
SELECT e 
FROM Entity e 
WHERE (e.parent = :parent OR e.parent IS NULL)
```

If you have further filters for your query then make sure to use `()` around your `OR` criteria like

```
SELECT e 
FROM Entity e 
WHERE (e.parent = :parent OR e.parent IS NULL)
AND e.some = :some...
```

Comment: I actually tried this one also, cause it makes sense. Unfornately it gives me a NonUniqueResult exception because it will give me 2 results when my parameter is not null. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5):

If your scenario is really that simple and you just want to get the entities (and don't really care about the query), then instead of DQL you can use a repository function:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('Entity')->findBy(array('parent' => $parent));
```

which will automatically special-case the SQL condition as "`parent IS NULL`" if `$parent` is `null` (else the basic condition "`parent = ?`" + parameter).

Otherwise, add a condition on `:parent` to avoid the NonUniqueResult exception in your combined query:

```
SELECT e 
FROM Entity e 
WHERE (e.parent = :parent OR (e.parent IS NULL AND :parent IS NULL))
```

or even (directly translating from your "hack"):

```
WHERE ((:parent IS NULL AND e.parent IS NULL) OR (:parent IS NOT NULL AND e.parent = :parent))
```

---

*Side note* about "NULL != NULL in SQL / DQL":

Strictly, both "NULL = NULL" and "NULL != NULL" *aren't either TRUE nor FALSE*: both return NULL.
Now, NULL isn't "truthy", so both queries
"`SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent = NULL`" and
"`SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.parent != NULL`"
won't ever return any row (for whatever data),
but NULL isn't "falsy" either (it is a third kind, say "undefined"), and negating it doesn't change that: "NOT (NULL)" is still NULL (and not TRUE), so
"`SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE NOT (e.parent = NULL)`" and
"`SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE NOT (e.parent != NULL)`"
won't ever return any row either!
Hence the need to use the operators "`x IS NULL`" and "`x IS NOT NULL`" (or "`NOT (x IS NULL)`") or `COALESCE()`, or vendor-specific functions like `ISNULL()`, `IFNULL()`, `NVL()`, etc.
(Remark: there can be cases where "undefinedness" is solved out automatically, e.g. in conditions
"*(expression that yields NULL)* OR *(expression that evaluates to TRUE)*" or
"*(expression that yields NULL)* AND *(expression that evaluates to FALSE)*"
because "*anything* OR TRUE" is always TRUE and "*anything* AND FALSE" is always FALSE.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question is fairly 'old', but maybe it'll help someone else out once.