# Symfony - Doctrine - Repository - WHERE value might be null or not

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Sometimes a `category` will have a value and sometimes it will be null (this condition is omitted).

The following will **not** return a `product` if it has a null `category`.

What's the best way to resolve this without having to check if `category` is null and then use `->where('product.category is null')`? I'm in a situation where I have 30 different fields where sometimes the value will be null and sometimes it won't.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('product')
    ->andWhere('product.category = :category')
    ->setParameter('category', $category)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult()
;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for. Are you looking for a shorthand for `WHERE some_field = some_value OR some_field IS NULL`?

Comment: $category will sometimes have a value and sometimes it will be 'null'.

If it is null then the query above won't find the product even though a product exists with a null category. What's the 'shortest' way to resolve this?

Comment: Ah, I see now, you need either equality or `is null`, based on what `$category` is. There is no simple, built-in functionality for this (or at least none that I know of), but you could always wrap this in a method.

Comment: Found an old question with the same problem I'm facing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405835/combine-is-null-and-value-in-doctrine-2-dql

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check for `null` by your own. You can do it in the next way:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('product');

if (null === $category) {
  $qb->andWhere('product.category IS NULL');
} else {
  $qb->andWhere('product.category = :category')
    ->setParameter('category', $category)
  ;
}

return $qb->getQuery()
  ->getOneOrNullResult()
;
```